# Retrieving user info from AAD using Graph REST API for not B2C users

Tags: azure-active-directory

I need to get users' names knowing their Azure AD IDs.
I was able to get this info by calling GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D), but only for B2C users.
If a user is not B2C I am getting a ServiceUnavailable response code.

Does it mean that I do not have permission?

Comment: Are you acquiring users of b2c tenants?

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be using Azure AD B2C access token, because you are acquiring users of B2C tenants.  The easiest way to check is to use [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) to parse your access token, and then check the `tid` claim, it should be the tenant id of your B2C tenant.

If you want to obtain user information for non-B2C tenants, such as users of AD tenants, you only need to change the `/tenant id` endpoint to the id of the **AD tenant** ,  then use the application of the AD tenant. Finally you can use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain an access token. Use this token to call the api, you should be able to obtain information about non-B2C users.